Using differentiation under the integral sign for computing the gradient of the expectation.
I am following the work from Kingma and Welling, where they introduce Variational Autoencoders. To train such models they use the so called Evidence Lower Bound and maximize it. One way to solve this optimization problem is by a gradient descent method, but to do so it is required to compute (or at least estimate) the gradients of the ELBO. One of the steps of the prove requires using the identity:
$$ \nabla_{\phi} \mathbb{E}_{p(\epsilon)}\left[f(\textbf{z})\right] =  \mathbb{E}_{p(\epsilon)}\left[\nabla_{\phi}f(\textbf{z})\right]$$
with $\textbf{z}=g(\textbf{x},\epsilon,\phi)$, with $g$ differentiable and invertible, and $f(\textbf{z}) = \log p_\theta(\textbf{x},\textbf{z}) - \log q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x})$. Here $p_\theta$ parameterizes the joint distribution between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{z}$, and $q_\phi$ approximates a posterior distribution. So, both are parameterized density functions.
I believe that proving the identity is an application of the Differentiation under the integral sign theorem:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $E$ be a measure space. Let
$f: U \times E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

For each $x \in U$, $f(x, \cdot)$ is integrable on $E$.

For each $y \in E$, $f(\cdot, y)$ is differentiable on $U$.

There exists an integrable function $g: E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)\right| \leq g(y)$$ for all $x \in U$ and $y \in
>     E$.
Then the function $F: U \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ F(x) = \int_E f(x, y) dy $$
is differentiable on $U$, and
$$ F'(x) = \int_E \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) dy. $$



The problem is that I cannot manage to properly fit the requirements of the theorem to my use-case. Specially I have trouble with finding a function that satisfies point 3 of the theorem. I have seen many posts on ELBO but all seem to skip details like this. I would appreciate any insights on the topic.
Thank you.
